# We have a triangle XYZ with a circumcircle T, whose incircle touches YZ, ZX, XY at A,B,C respectively.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

We have a triangle XYZ who has a circumcircle T which has an incircle that touches YZ, ZX, XY at A,B,C respectively. A circle is drawn tangent to segment YZ at A and to minor arc YZ of T at point $A_1$. $B_1$ and $C_1$ are defined similarly. How do you Prove that lines $A_1A$, $B_1B$,$C_1C$ are concurrent?
[image: diagram]

I think that the mini circles being tangent to the triangle may come in handy when solving this problem, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let the in-center be I. $AA_1$ is just the extension of $IAA_1$. The other two lines are similarly defined. Hence they are concurrent at I.